# Need carousel to be 100% with position absolute

Tags: html, css, height, width, carousel

I am trying to put a rotating carousel together and it cant get it to do what i want it to.
I want it to be 100% width and for the height to adjust accordingly, pushing down content under it.

Whenever i resize the window, the absolute positioned images are coming out the container that should be resizing.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

This is my setup. The rotation works fine as I have the relevant javascript set up. Its just the height i'm having trouble with.

html

```
    <div id="myslider">
    <img src="myurl" class="active" >
    <img src="myurl">
    </div>
```

css

```
    #myslider {
    position:relative;
    width:100%; 

    }


    #myslider IMG {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:8;
    opacity:0.0;

    }


    #myslider IMG.active {
    z-index:10;
    opacity:1.0;
    }


    #myslider IMG.last-active {
    z-index:9;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, if you set img width to 100%

```
#myslider IMG {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:8;
  opacity:0.0;
  width: 100%; /* add this */ 
}
```

A codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JEphu

That will cause your image to always be 100% of it's container. It this case, your #myslider div. The height will vary based on the ratio of the image.